# Why one white space could make a new line? How to make the line with space(s) in one line

Tags: html, css, html-email

```html
<table width="600">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <span>Price:</span> </td>
      <td width="100%">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="width:100%;border-bottom:3px dotted #0b863c">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>$30.9 sdfsdfd fgertwet</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So I am trying to create a email template. It contains dynamic content with space. Every time when it has space inside the third column, it will create a new line. But I only want it to be in one line.

I know it works with `white-space: no-wrap`. However, white-space doesn't support in outlook -- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/.  Any other ideas? Thanks!

See Expected:

```html
<table width="600">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <span>Price:</span> </td>
      <td width="100%">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="width:100%;border-bottom:3px dotted #0b863c">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap;">$30.9 sdfsdfd fgertwet</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty much default behavior of text in HTML.

If you have control over the dynamic content, you could replace the spaces with non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) as in the following example.

```html
<table width="600">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <span>Price:</span> </td>
      <td width="100%">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="width:100%;border-bottom:3px dotted #0b863c">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>$30.9&nbsp;sdfsdfd&nbsp;fgertwet</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Finally, I apply `white-space: no-wrap`, because our template loader will escape non-breaking space, so it can't be applied. But still thanks for your help!